# How can I use one calculated field for other filter condition in mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb

I have properties data in mongoDB having fields { ListPrice, ClosePrice } and I wish to have those properties which ListPrice is less than the average of ClosePrice of all selected properties.

First I have calculate the average of ClosePrice and then trying to implement $cond for checking if ListPrice is less than push that data in a field.

I expect to get data having ListPrice less than or equal to ClosePrice.

```
 db.collection('properties').aggregate([
    {
       $group:{
        _id: 1,
        avgClosePrice: { $avg: "$ClosePrice" },
        data : {
            $push : {
                $cond: [
                    {
                      $lte: ["$ListPrice", "$avgClosePrice"]
                    },
                    "$ListPrice",
                    0
                  ]
            }
        },
      } 
    },
  ]
    ).limit(100).toArray((err, response)=> {
if(err) console.log(err)
else console.log(response)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be difficult to achieve this in one stage, but you can break it in multiple stages and get the desired result.

Try this :

```
 db.collection('properties').aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            _id: 1,
            avgClosePrice: { $avg: "$ClosePrice" },
            ListPrice : {$first  : "$ListPrice"}
        }
    },{
        $project : {
            avgClosePrice : "$avgClosePrice",
            data : {
                $expr : {
                    $cond : [
                        {
                            $lt : ["$ListPrice", "$avgClosePrice"]
                        },
                        "$ListPrice",
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },{
        $group : {
            _id : "$_id",
            avgClosePrice : {$first : "$avgClosePrice"},
            data : {$push : "$data"}
        }
    }
  ]
).limit(100).toArray((err, response)=> {
    if(err) console.log(err)
    else console.log(response)
}
```

Comment: It shows errmsg:"Unrecognized expression '$expr'". I have also tried without $expr creating multiple stage. but It didn't work .

Comment: let me try and get back to you